# Configure log4j to send email

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

In log4j.properties I have

```
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [correlation-ids:%X{X-CAAP-Correlation-ID},user:%X{X-CAAP-User}] [%t] (%C:%L) %X{camel.routeId}- %m%n

log4j.logger.com.lacapitale=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO


log4j.appender.SMTP=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.SMTP.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.SMTP.From=noreply@mycompany.com
log4j.appender.SMTP.SMTPHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SMTP.Subject=[{{appid}}] - Erreur technique
log4j.appender.SMTP.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.SMTP.To=me@mycompany.com
log4j.appender.SMTP.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SMTP.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE

log4j.logger.email=INFO, SMTP
```

But, I never get any email when I log an info.

Is there anything wrong in my config?

Is it because I deployed the app in Eclipse embedded Tomcat? Does Tomcat always include a SMTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat does not include an SMTP server.  You will need to make sure the SMTPHost you have defined has an MTA installed, running, and accepting connections.